# Why is merging at center in Blender deleting/deselecting my vertex, or why can’t I select it?

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, modifiers

So I’m trying to create a tube in Blender to create a dreadlock for my character model. I added a sphere, went into Edit Mode (I’ve added no modifiers, mind you), and, with all vertices of this sphere selected, tried to merge them into a single vertex in the middle.

[image: The selected sphere in Edit Mode]

But when I do, the entire sphere disappears (as expected), but the vertex isn’t selected, nor is it really there. I thought that because it was just been one vertex, it wouldn’t be easy to see, so I tried to select it by dragging the mouse across the area, but nothing is highlighted, or shown as selected in the transform panel.

[image: After merging]

I thought that I would continue and add modifiers (skin, and two subdivision modifiers) and it does show, yet I cannot select the vertex.

[image: Added Skin Modifier]

[image: Added Subdivision Modifiers]

I see that this is a problem because if the vertex isn’t selected I can’t extrude it or anything. I am still considered a beginner, as it might be obvious; if someone would be so kind as to explain if I am doing something wrong and what exactly I should do, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can't select it because you are in *Face Select* mode, switch to *Vertex Select* mode:

[image]

Comment: Wrote my whole answer without even thinking of that - good eye ;)

Comment: it's because it happened to me several days ago aha  ;)

Comment: Wow this works too, I didn't even notice this — I am still learning, so I thank you as well :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to work with single vertices in the future, a good method is to enable the built-in addon *Add Mesh: Extra Objects*. Enable this in the addon section of the preferences menu, and it will add the ability to add a Single Vert from the Mesh menu:

[image: Mesh1]

[image: Mesh2]

Comment: Ah! Thank you, this seems a lot easier. 'Preciate it!